# How can i convert this recursive depth first search into a depth limited search?

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I've been trying to change this depth first search into a depth limited search but so far i haven't been able to figure out a way to do so. any ideas?

```
        // A function used by DFS 
void DFSUtil(int v,boolean visited[]) 
{ 
    // Mark the current node as visited and print it 
    visited[v] = true; 
    System.out.print(v+" "); 

    // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex 
    Iterator<Integer> i = adj[v].listIterator(); 
    while (i.hasNext()) 
    { 
        int n = i.next(); 
        if (!visited[n]) 
            DFSUtil(n, visited); 
    } 
} 

// The function to do DFS traversal. It uses recursive DFSUtil() 
void DFS(int v) 
{ 
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited(set as 
    // false by default in java) 
    boolean visited[] = new boolean[V]; 

    // Call the recursive helper function to print DFS traversal 
    DFSUtil(v, visited); 
}
```

Comment: Please define "depth limited search". Please post [mcve] including test data end expected result

Answer (score -1):

If i get you correctly you want to search till the limit then you can use the counter and compare with the limit in `DFSUtil` function with the limited value.

Comment: "search till the limit" what limit ?